# After package.json updating got error about polyfills angular 2 webpack

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, upgrade, package

I am working with ng2 based on the webpack   and it was working fine till I update the package.json. After that I have some errors.
Could someone help me, please, where is the issue? Thank for any help!

P.s. My project based on the official ng2 webpack example.

```
Cannot find module 'enhanced-resolve/lib/getInnerRequest'
     @ multi polyfillserrors @ client?cd17:75sock.onmessage @ socket.js:37EventTarget.dispatchEvent @ eventtarget.js:51(anonymous function) @ main.js:274SockJS._transportMessage @ main.js:272EventEmitter.emit @ emitter.js:50WebSocketTransport.ws.onmessage @ websocket.js:35

Cannot find module 'enhanced-resolve/lib/getInnerRequest'
     @ multi vendorerrors @ client?cd17:75sock.onmessage @ socket.js:37EventTarget.dispatchEvent @ eventtarget.js:51(anonymous function) @ main.js:274SockJS._transportMessage @ main.js:272EventEmitter.emit @ emitter.js:50WebSocketTransport.ws.onmessage @ websocket.js:35
    Cannot find module 'enhanced-resolve/lib/getInnerRequest'
     @ multi app
```

here is my current packge.json

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Test Project",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --colors --port 8080",
    "deploy": "rimraf dist && webpack --config config/webpack.prod.js --progress --profile --bail",
    "postinstall": "typings install",
    "test": "karma start"
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.2.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.2.3",
    "@angular/core": "2.2.3",
    "@angular/forms": "2.2.3",
    "@angular/http": "2.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.2.3",
    "@angular/router": "3.2.3",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.37",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "jquery": "^3.1.1",
    "ng2-redux": "^4.0.0-beta.0",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-rc.4",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jquery": "^2.0.34",
    "angular2-router-loader": "^0.3.3",
    "angular2-template-loader": "^0.6.0",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^3.0.0-beta.3",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.26.0",
    "css-sourcemaps-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.3",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.1",
    "file-loader": "^0.9.0",
    "html-loader": "^0.4.3",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.15.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.4.1",
    "karma": "^1.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.7",
    "karma-webpack": "^1.8.0",
    "node-sass": "^3.10.1",
    "phantomjs-prebuilt": "^2.1.7",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.8",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^1.6.0",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.2",
    "sass-loader": "^4.0.2",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "ts-loader": "^1.2.2",
    "typescript": "^2.0.2",
    "typings": "^2.0.0",
    "webpack": "^1.13.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1",
    "webpack-glob": "^2.0.2",
    "webpack-merge": "^0.18.0",
    "webpack-spritesmith": "^0.3.0",
    "webpack-svgstore-plugin": "^3.0.5"
  }
}
```

my previous package.json (working)

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Test Project",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --colors --port 8080",
    "deploy": "rimraf dist && webpack --config config/webpack.prod.js --progress --profile --bail",
    "postinstall": "typings install",
    "test": "karma start"
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.1.2",
    "@angular/core": "2.1.2",
    "@angular/forms": "2.1.2",
    "@angular/http": "2.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.1.2",
    "@angular/router": "3.1.2",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.37",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "jquery": "^3.1.1",
    "ng2-redux": "^4.0.0-beta.0",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-rc.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.23"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jquery": "^2.0.34",
    "angular2-router-loader": "^0.3.3",
    "angular2-template-loader": "^0.6.0",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^2.2.4",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.25.0",
    "css-sourcemaps-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.3",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.1",
    "file-loader": "^0.9.0",
    "html-loader": "^0.4.3",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.15.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.4.1",
    "karma": "^1.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.7",
    "karma-webpack": "^1.8.0",
    "node-sass": "^3.10.1",
    "phantomjs-prebuilt": "^2.1.7",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.8",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^1.6.0",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.2",
    "sass-loader": "^4.0.2",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "ts-loader": "^0.9.5",
    "typescript": "^2.0.2",
    "typings": "^1.3.2",
    "webpack": "^1.13.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1",
    "webpack-glob": "^2.0.2",
    "webpack-merge": "^0.15.0",
    "webpack-spritesmith": "^0.3.0",
    "webpack-svgstore-plugin": "^3.0.5"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in a webpack dependency. I manually installed the plugin
enhanced-resolve and it is working now.
I hope it helps to someone and saves some nerves

Comment: Hello Velidan. Looks like I have the same problem. Can you elaborate how you used the enhanced-resolve plugin please?